# Incorrect implementation of the many to many relationship Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I would be appreciated if you would help me.
I have several Postgress' tables:

1. **doctor**
2. **patient**
3. **doctor_patient**

When I'm trying to add the patient to the doctor's table (many to many relationships), my **doctor_patient** table contains only the latest record. I really don't understand why (:

Here is my implementation:

**PatientController:**

```
 @PostMapping("/users/{userId}/patients")
public ResponseEntity<?> addPatient(@PathVariable(value = "userId") final Long userId,
                                    @Valid @RequestBody final Patient patient) {

    if (patientRepository.existsByPatientEmail(patient.getPatientEmail())) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiResponse(false, "Patient email is already taken!"),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    if (patientRepository.existsByPatientCellPhone(patient.getPatientCellPhone())) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiResponse(false, "Cell phone already in use!"),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    if(!userRepository.existsById(userId)) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiResponse(false, "User by id is not found!"),
                HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    userRepository.getById(userId).map(item -> {
        final Set<Patient> patients = new HashSet<>();
        patients.add(patient);
        item.setPatients(patients);
        userRepository.save(item);
        return item;
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Following user is not found!"));

    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiResponse(true, "Patient created successfully"), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Patient entity:**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "patients")
private Set<Doctor> doctors = new HashSet<>();
```

**Doctor entity:**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "doctor_patients",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private Set<Patient> patients = new HashSet<>();
```

**Patient table:**

[Image of patient table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqwiH.png)

**Doctor table:**

[Image of doctor table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJdRn.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
    final Set<Patient> patients = new HashSet<>();
    patients.add(patient);
    item.setPatients(patients);
    userRepository.save(item);
    return item;
```

There is a mistake in this part of your code. You probably want to get the list of patients and add a new one, but you just creating a fresh list each time. Also, just IMHO, you stated that there is many to many but it's not allowed to add an existing user to another doctor.

Comment: `@PostMapping("/users/{userId}/patients")
public ResponseEntity<?> addPatient(@PathVariable(value = "userId") final Long userId,
                                    @Valid @RequestBody final Patient patient) {`

Thanks for your answer. 

I'm trying to find the doctor by Id (provided via request param) and assign that doctor the new patient (also provided via request body). But nothing happens (( I really do not know how to solve that. Maybe should I find a doctor by id, retrieve the list of patients and update those list?

Comment: thank you very much!!!!! I've saved my time!!!! I've changed my code, according to tour suggestions an now it works as expected!!!!